# Deploying database changes to a firewalled environment

Tags: sql-server, deployment, msbuild, database-project

Our situation is as follows: we have a dev environment (local machine) on which we develop against a LocalDB instance. We also have a test environment within our network that has its own test database.

When we deploy the (ASP.NET) application to the client, we're using a TFS build server to generate a web deployment package that we send to them so they can import the package in IIS in their acceptance and production environment. Their IIS and database are behind a firewall (bigcorp policies unfortunately) so we can't use MSDeploy to directly push our code from our build server to their environment.

At first I thought about just letting SSMS generate change scripts and bundle them with the deployment package to be executed manually, but I couldn't find a way to include them in the deployment package automatically (which kind of destroys the point of having a build server) so we thought about using a database project that we can build and that creates the change scripts for us, together with the deployment packages for the code.

I have a few questions about this:

1. Can I generate incremental change scripts when I want to deploy to an 'offline' environment? How do I do this? Doesn't this mean I need a database connection with the remote server so I can compare it with the local server?
2. How does it find out what changed? Does it look at the local database (the test database probably) during the build process to see what has changed since last time? Or are the changes stored in the project itself?
3. Can I still develop database changes in SSMS, or do I need to make them in Visual Studio in the database project for them to be picked up?

Can anyone describe a workflow that works in my setting and does what I'm trying to do?

Maybe needless to say, but we're using TFS 2013 with Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2014.

Comment: If you're using SQL Projects in SSDT, you'd give them the dacpac file from your build and maybe a batch file they can tweak to run SQLPackage and push the changes to their server. That will do a diff to see what changes need to be applied. I would recommend a publish profile as well to help control those changes.  SQLPackage will compare the expected schema in your dacpac w/ the actual on the DB Server and generate a change script (or just push changes).  You would do your dev in SSDT.  https://schottsql.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/all-ssdt-articles/

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use Database Projects in VS which produce DACPACs to represent the database.
2. At deploy time it will compare the DACPAC to the target database and create a diff script on the fly
3. Use VS.  We were sceptical at first but really prefer it now.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/

Comment: Would you mind answering all of my questions? You didn't really address any of my questions (at least not by giving an answer to the exact questions I was asking).

Comment: I'm sorry I thought I answered your questions 1-3.  How can I improve my answer? What question(s) were not answered?